# To find the position of row based on two column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, python-3.6

I have 2 columns in the dataframe which is as follows:

```
report  pname
 D      Singapore
 N      Pradip
 A      
 S      Singapore
 D
 y      Europe
```

I am performing the validation on column values.In the column report the valid values can be D and N and A and if other than these values occur it producs the error and the index.

But Now I want to perform the validation simultaneously on the two columns(report,pname). If the report has vale D and A the column should not be empty(null).If it is null for D and A column values of report it should generate the error.

The code which i have done is for one column validation .

```
lst=list(df['report'])
lst
lst1=['D','N','A']

def valid_reportype(v, lst):
    if v in lst1:
       return True
    return False
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if not valid_reportype(v, lst):
       print(f"value {v} at index {i} for column Reporting_Type is Invalid")
```

My code just does the validation of one column that is other that D,N,A values are present it produces errror.

I wanted to check the two column values simultaneously that is is D and A are the value the pname column values sholud not be null.If it is it should produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not getting all the bad entries at once in the `pandas` way with:

```
invalid_lines = df[~df['report'].isin(lst1) | (pd.isna(df['pname']) & df['report'].isin(['A', 'D']))]
```

Then you can print them with:

```
for i in range(len(invalid_lines)):
    print("value " + str(invalid_lines.iloc[i, 0]) + " at index " + str(invalid_lines.index[i]) + " for column Reporting_Type is Invalid")
```

Comment: it works but for pname column i want check for just  D and A ......If the values are D and A the pname cannot be empty@Aryerez

Comment: can u tell me how to proceed for that in function @Aryerez

Comment: @arpita So if you have *N* in `report` column, it's ok for `pname` to be empty?

Comment: can u tell me how to proceed with these logic in the function.....bcz i want to display on which lines it does not satisfy @Aryerez